# Why here after dann, the verb is at the end?

Tags: word-order

Why here after dann, the verb is at the end? Based on my knowledge, after dann always we have a verb.

> Der Junge in der Tankstelle hat den Kassenbeleg mit diesem Kuli unterschrieben und ihn dann auf der Theke gelassen.

Comment: Das "dann" hat nichts zu tun mit der verbalen VE-Stellung.

Comment: Die Vermutung, dass nach *dann* immer ein Verb kommt, ist alles andere als abwegig. Wenn diese Frage jetzt schon off-topic ist, können wir den Laden hier auch einfach dicht machen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on my knowledge, after *dann* always we have a verb.

Well, no.

*Dann* is a *Temporaladverb*. In many cases it stands before anything about a place - like it does in your example.

> ... und ihn dann<sub>(when)</sub> auf der Theke<sub>(where)</sub> gelassen.

But not even that is a strict rule. The only strict rule is: the verb is in second position.

If you want the verb after *dann*, you can rearrange your example sentence like this:

> Der Junge hat den Kassenbeleg mit diesem Kuli unterschrieben. Dann hat er ihn auf der Theke gelassen.

The verb *hat* is left out in the second part of the sentence.

> Der Junge hat den Kassenbeleg mit diesem Kuli unterschrieben und [hat] ihn dann auf der Theke gelassen.

This is a perfectly fine sentence. Your presumed rule just doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, wobei es mit "... gelassen auf der Theke" auch richtig wäre, allerdings umganggsprachlich. Was dann aber gar nichts zu tun mit dann hätte, siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: @Dan Nah, not really.

Answer (score 1):

The verbs of both parts of the sentences are in tempus *Perfekt*

> Der Junge in der Tankstelle *hat* den Kassenbeleg mit diesem Kuli *unterschrieben* und ihn dann auf der Theke *gelassen*.

Comment: While this is correct, could you please add a sentence or two, why the verbs being in *Perfekt* leads to the verb's position at the end? That might not be obvious for a learner.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular clause with direct word order, the past participle goes to the end, hence "gelassen" at the very end.

In the informal speech, it is well possible to say:

> Der Junge in der Tankstelle hat den Kassenbeleg mit diesem Kuli unterschrieben und ihn dann gelassen auf der Theke.

This would be the case of the so-called *Ausklammerung beim Präpositionalobjekt*. However, it has **nothing** to do with dann. If you wonder why "dann" came first, this is because of the broader Te-Ka-Mo-Lo rule. If your confusion came from experiencing somthing like that in informal colloquial German, you now have the explanation.

Comment: Informal speech in which region? I know of no German dialect where this sentence structure would be considered acceptable.

Comment: http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Ausklammerung#Ausklammerung_von_Pr.C3.A4positionalphrasen

Comment: Fürhter examplex: https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1118

Comment: Noch ein schönes Beispiel: " (39) Mit dem Unterschied nur, dass die Touristen zurückkehren können ins eigeneHeim. (16.04.07, Nr. 88, S.8" https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/56344940.pdf

Und noch ein Paar aus demselben Buch: 1) Aufgeräumt gibt der Verehrte zu Protokoll, dass er nicht traurig sei über den Ab-schied...
2) Die Todesserie in der Kleinstadt reiht sich ein in die Alkohol-Katastrophenmeldungen russischer Zeitungen und der staatlich kontrollierten Fern-sehersender „Erster Kanal“ und „Russland.“

Comment: "Weil er sich entmündigt fühlt im eigenen Land " - hier haben wir eine Kombination aus V2-weil und präpositionaler Ausklammerung. Köstlich :)